# Given a git commit hash, how to find out which kernel release contains it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, git, source

Assume I have some issue that was fixed by a recent patch to the official Linux git repository. I have a work around, but I’d like to undo it when a release happens that contains my the fix. I know the exact git commit hash, e.g. [f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c](http://repo.or.cz/w/linux-2.6.git/commit/f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c).

What is the easiest way to answer the question: What kernel releases so far contain this patch? Bonus points if no local Linux git repository is needed.

([LWM](http://lwn.net/Articles/392293/) discusses some ideas, but these do require a local repository.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [GitHub kernel repository](https://github.com/torvalds/linux), you can check all tags/kernel versions.

Example for [dc0827c128c0ee5a58b822b99d662b59f4b8e970](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/dc0827c128c0ee5a58b822b99d662b59f4b8e970) provided by [Jim Paris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21804/jim-paris):

[image: Commit dc0827c@GitHub]

If three-dots are clicked, full list of tags/kernel versions can be seen.

Answer (score 24):

As [mentioned on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/392293/), the easiest is:

```
git describe --contains f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c
```

If you don't want a local clone, gitweb's "plain" formatted commit contains the same info in the `X-Git-Tag` header. *Unfortunately kernel.org switched over to cgit which apparently does not disclose this information.* Previously it was possible to find it out like this:

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c

Here, `X-Git-Tag` is actually missing at the moment because that commit isn't in a tagged release in that repository.  But you can look at an earlier commit, like:

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=dc0827c128c0ee5a58b822b99d662b59f4b8e970

Here, you see:

```
X-Git-Tag: v3.4-rc1~184^2~10
```

which tells me that the tag "v3.4-rc1" was the first tag to follow my patch, so I'd expect to see it in v3.4.

Comment: Not sure if this is answer is valid anymore. X-Git-Tag does not appear.

Comment: The first sentence is still valid.  Finding the answer through gitweb is no longer an option, but that's why this question was edited almost 3 years ago to say just that.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I was surprised no answer included:

```
git tag --contains <Commit ID>
```

From git tag help message:

```
Tag listing options
     --contains <commit>   print only tags that contain the commit
```

This requires a local GIT repository.

Since this question was the first result I got when looking for a solution, I think this would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
git-show f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c:Makefile \
         | head -4 | awk -vORS='.' '{print $3}' | sed 's/\.*$//'
```

This requires local git repo.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the commit on the [github source mirror.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f3a1ef9cee4812e2d08c855eb373f0d83433e34c) I suppose you could correllate the [release tags](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags) to the commit date (in this case, your commit is five days old, the most recent tagged RC on `master` is seven), but frankly this is easier to get at if you clone the source locally.

Comment: Correlating the date won't work since the patch may not be merged into any release yet, or it may have been written originally for a previous release and just not merged until more recently.

Comment: Nowadays GitHub shows all tags containing a specific commit just below the commit message, so no need to correlate by date anymore.