# How do I know which kernel version will have a bug fix I need?

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a git patch id, how to find out which kernel release contains it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45120/given-a-git-patch-id-how-to-find-out-which-kernel-release-contains-it)

I encountered a [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49586/no-sound-with-the-newest-kernel-version-is-this-a-kernel-bug-or-something-else) in one of the newer kernel versions. There is no workaround; if I want to have sound at my system at all, I have to boot an older kernel version. Since this is a home computer I use for video and music, I need the sound and haven't updated the kernel since 3.5.4-2, not wanting to overwrite the version which still works.

There already is a [fix](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=8dce30c89113e314d29d3b8f362aadff8087fccb) which repairs the problem. But I don't know when it will be included in a kernel update. How do I find out which kernel version will contain the fix? I don't want to update until this version comes out.

Comment: As a general rule, it is not a particularly good idea to update your kernel _very_ often. 3.5.4-2 is a very recent kernel (less than two months old), unless there is a specific functionality in one of the new ones, I would stick with it until a major update comes out.

Comment: @terdon I have Fedora, it automatically pushes out the most recent kernels in the stable version. Right now, I have 3.5.5-2 sitting in yum, urging me to install it.

Comment: Ignore it. As I said, upgrading your kernel with no specific reason is a recipe for the kind of problems you are experiencing. Just add this to `/etc/yum.conf`: `exclude=kernel*`. Then, in a few months, if you feel you should update your kernel, do so manually. Just remember the golden rule: [IIABDFI](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/IIABDFI). On my debian system I am perfectly happy with my 3.2.0-3 kernel and I don't think I'll update unless something really worthwhile comes around.

Comment: @terdon. Nothing wrong with your explanation, but the link to IIABDFI is terrible :). It took me time to find the relevant text inside all those ads

Comment: @FrancescoTurco, crap, you're quite right, sorry. I just took the 1st google hit.

Comment: @terdon: That is **incredibly** bad advice.  The stable kernels address security and data-loss problems.  See, for example, the [release announcement](https://lwn.net/Articles/518342/) for 3.5.5: "All users of the 3.5 kernel series must upgrade."  Telling users to `exclude=kernel*` is like telling a Windows user to disable automatic updates.

Comment: @terdon: Also, you say "On my debian system I am perfectly happy with my 3.2.0-3 kernel".  Debian's 3.2.0-3 is based on upstream 3.2.21, which is outdated, but **still** only 3.5 months old.

Comment: @terdon, @rumtscho: Finally, in this specific case: the patch in question **was** included in 3.5.5, so you should stop ignoring `yum` and just install it already.  It will fix your problem.

Comment: @JimParis, I am not saying one should never update the kernel. The OP specifically does not want to, so disabling yum's automatic notification is a perfectly good short-term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Given a git patch id, how to find out which kernel release contains it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45120/given-a-git-patch-id-how-to-find-out-which-kernel-release-contains-it/45152#45152)

In short: from your "fix" link, click "commitdiff" at the top, click "raw", and look at the `X-Git-Tag` header.